# Changing HTML div's background colour when it is clicked using JavaScript without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to implement a very simple feature, using only JavaScript without jQuery. I want the background of the HTML div with `id='tags'` to change, when I click on it.

```js
document.getElementById('tags').addEventListener('onclick', function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="tags">Item1</div>
  <div id='tags'>Item2</div>
  <div id='tags'>Item3</div>
</body>
```

Comment: The fundamental rule of id's is that its unique! and you are really killing that fundamental rule. It can only be assigned a unique value

Answer (score 2):

1. **Identiifiers** in HTML must be **unique**, Use a common CSS class to instead.
2. Use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to target them, as it will return a list, iterate it and bind event handlers
3. remove prefixed "on"

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.tags').forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  });
})
```

```html
<div class="tags">Item1</div>
<div class='tags'>Item2</div>
<div class='tags'>Item3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A few issues here:

1. your script is (or was before you edited the question) executing before the `<div>` elements are added to the document; the `<script>` needs to be placed after the `<div>`s in your HTML source code.
2. you can't have multiple elements with the same `id`. use `class="tags"` instead.
3. the event is `"click"` not `"onclick"`

Here's what i'd do instead:

```html
<body>
 <div class="tags">Item1</div>
 <div class="tags">Item2</div>
 <div class="tags">Item3</div>
 <script>
  for (let x of document.getElementsByClassName('tags')) {
   x.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
   });
  }
 </script>
</body>
```